# use case for a do-while loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm aware that "do-while" will run atleast once compared to "while" which has to satisfy a condition to run.

Is this correct usecase of do-while?

```
do{
  var ajaxresponse = make an ajax call and assign the response to the variable.
while( ajaxresponse.length == <some number>);
```

Comment: No. AJAX = Asynchronous ....

Comment: ^ Loop = synchronous

Comment: @FelixKling: `do { await fetch(…); } while (…)` :-P

Answer (score 1):

If you were to make the AJAX call synchronous, this would be valid.

ex.

```
$.ajax({url:"url",..., async: false});
```

BUT, this totally defeats the point of AJAX being asynchronous, so should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

For iterating and performing operations on response data, it's better to do that in callback function. Because AJAX is asynchronous. Following code uses Jquery for Ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( ajaxresponse ) {

    do{
    //operations
    }while(ajaxresponse.length == <some number> );

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

When JavaScript runs in a web client, it runs synchronously - meaning only one thread of execution for JavaScript is possible at a time.

Because of this, if a function makes a call for an asynchronous operation to be performed (like `XmlHttpRequest.send` or `setTimeout`), that operation is handled via a WebAPI  by the browser OUTSIDE of the JavaScript runtime in a separate thread and the callbacks for that operation are then queued up and are executed when the JavaScript runtime is idle.

In your code:

```
do{
  var ajaxresponse = make an ajax call and assign the response to the variable.
while( ajaxresponse.length == <some number>);
```

the `ajaxresponse` won't come back until the function containing the do/while loop completes, so when your while condition checks the `ajaxresponse`, there won't be a value to check.